# Adding default notifications to calendar

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I add a default notification(s) to my Google Calendar, using google apps script? 
[I mean this notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arIgk.jpg)
So, if I create a new CalendarApp 
`bdayNotifyCal = CalendarApp.createCalendar("Birthday Notifications");`
There's no any method allows to edit default calendars's notifications.

Comment: You may be able to use the Advanced Google Service for the Calendar API.  Under the "Resources" menu in the code editor, choose "Advanced Google Services"  Enable the Calendar API by turning the button to ON.  For documentation about the public Calendar API to insert default settings click the following [Link to public Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert)  There are "built-in" services like "CalendarApp" that don't need to explicitly be turned on.  The "Advanced Google Service" is simply a way to access the public API.

Comment: You are correct, that there is no method for the "built-in" CalendarApp service to set default calendar settings, like default notifications.  The Advanced Google Services ***inside*** of Apps Script may handle the OAuth automatically.  Using the public API's externally typically require some code to handle the authorization with OAuth.

Comment: AFAIK the screenshot link that you provide is accessible thru the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). Thre is no exact guide on the Google Apps Script documentation on how to do this. What can I give you is this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341148) that create a notification by using appscript. So just check it if you can get idea with it. Also, this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addSmsReminder) can show you the things that you can do with calendar by using appscript.